# Drawing on the ImageView

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, ondraw

I am trying to draw on the ImageView (like a simple paint but just on the image). I have created a custom MyImageView class that extends ImageView where I override onDraw. I would like the ImageView to be at the center of the screen.

When I use one layout the image appears in the TOP LEFT CORNER and I can draw on top of it with no problems.

[image]

When I use a different layout, the image appears at the center of the screen **BUT** the canvas still remains this small little rectangle at the top left corner. So when I try to draw on the image I can only do it in the top left corner and the changes appear on the image at the center.

[image]

In my MainActivity I set:

```
myImageView = (MyImageView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);

// I also extract the bitmap myBitmap from the pdf ...
// and pass it to the ImageView
myImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

// and I set the Canvas too:
Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
myImageView.setMyCanvas(myCanvas);
```

Then here are the crucial parts of the MyImageView:

```
public class MyImageView extends 
    android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    // variables...

    public MyImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setupDrawing();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    }

    private void setupDrawing() { //...usual stuff here }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { //...usual stuff here }

    public void setMyCanvas(Canvas canvas) { this.myCanvas = canvas; }
```

Do I have to add/change sth in MyImageView or MainActivity so that the canvas will be only on top of the ImageView or at least stretch across the whole screen?

Comment: Can you add your onDraw() method's code here. Have you hard coded values there? Also, the second case looks like you have set the width and height to match_parent for the image view, which is why you are getting the complete area as your canvas.

Comment: I think adding 
        android:gravity="center"
 to your linear layout should make it work as desired.

Answer (score 1):

There's not relationship between Canvas origin and the ImageView scaleType or gravity.

The X, Y origin of Canvas is always the top-left corner of the View, if you want to paint in other part of the View you need to translate the coordinates by your own.

**ADDED**
First thing to understand is that canvas is for draw over all the view not only over the image you choose.

To center the Path drawing then you need to do something like this in your onDraw

```
canvas.save();
canvas.translate( (getWidth() - pathWidth) / 2, (getHeight() - pathHeight) / 2);
canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
canvas.restore();
```

More than a programming problem is an arithmetic one.

Comment: I updated my question, could you please elaborate on your answer a little bit?

Comment: Thank you. What is pathWidth and pathHeight in this case?

Comment: The drawPath width & height you use in your code, if you created it you should know its dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

for,  ImageView to be AT THE CENTER OF THE SCREEN. modify your layout as follows

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#EEEEEE">

        <com.example.android.samplepaint.MyImageView
            android:id="@+id/pdfView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason lies in the choice of your layout. Because of the problem of screen adaptation, each layout needs to be bound to elements, and some layout defaults to the upper left corner.